# rpt file and datasource .. error reporting

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, report

We developing and correcting a project in visual studio 2005.in this solution i have 2 projects.
 The people project has a pr_personalID.rpt file (report) that use in Project and work correctly. When I publish project in other computer don’t work this Report but work correctly in my computer .
I have copied my solution(*.sln) in another PC on V.S and don’t work correctly! It worked correctly when I change the path of “Dataset.xsd” Of report to local path in new PC and its Worked! 
I thinks This is absolute address and in each PC don’t work correctly because of changing. Should I relative address in this case (in set datasource Location) or has another way to resolve this problem?

**

> this is my Whole solution:

**

[image]

> this is The error after run  *.rpt file  :

[image]

> this is data source and local address of dataset.xsd .

XSD file located in Main Project and *.rpt file used in people project
[image]

Comment: This is to do with Datasource settings of the report. Considering you have a subreport  as well, are you passing the datasource settings for the subreport? Also on your question please change you line "this is my HOLE solution" to "this is WHOLE solution". Its very funny.

Comment: :) i made mistake :) ...i currect it . could u please more about "passing the datasource settings for the subreport" ?